# FirefoxDiver is getting stopped after I run Selenium tests

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am getting the message whenever I am running tests on `FirefoxDriver` using Selenium

> A problem caused the program to stop working please close the program

My firefox version is 38.0.5

Comment: This is very little information to go on. What is it you are testing? Have you been able to single it out to a specific test(code) ?

Comment: After clicking that message away does the test start running? In my case it does after showing the message.

Comment: Yes after clicking that message away, the tests are running.